# Caption alignment problems in minipages and subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I failed to center all captions in each subfigure like this[image]. Captions in the left part (four subfigures "A") are not at the center I think. Captions in the right part (four dependencies) are aligned on the left and the line width of the caption does not work properly as well. Can anyone help me with this problem? I just want to center each caption.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{subfiles}
%\subfile{graphs/q_value.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{line}=[bend right=30,thin]
\pgfmathsetmacro\myscale{0.95}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
%\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
%The first part of subfigure
\begin{minipage}[h]{.60\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.45]{example-image-a}

\caption*{(1) 1st iteration}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.45]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(2) 2nd iteration}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.45]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(3) 3rd iteration}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.45]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(4) Final prediction}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{.30\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
%add----
\deproot[thick,dotted,edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
\deproot[red, edge height=30pt]{4}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(1) 1st iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
%add----
\deproot[thick,dotted,edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(2) 2nd iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
%add----
\deproot[edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(3) 3rd iteration}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
%add----
\deproot[edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(4) Final prediction}
\end{subfigure}

\end{minipage}

%\end{minipage}
%End of The first part of subfigure
%The second part of subfigure
%PSD ood test set
\caption{}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\includegraphics[scale=.45]{...}`, write `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`.

Comment: Please also tell us how the `dependency` and `deptext` environments and the `\deproot` and `\depedge` macros are defined.

Comment: I update the code, it can be compiled now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two main adjustments:

- In the left-hand `minipage`, replace all instances of `[scale=.45]` with either `[width=\textwidth]` or `[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]`.
- In the right-hand `minipage`, replace all instances of `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}` with `\begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}`.

Two additional comments: (a) Don't load the obsolete and unmaintained `latexsym` package. Instead, load the `amssmyb` package. (b) Don't load packages more than once -- nothing good will come out of it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{times}
%%%%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}%%%{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
%%%%\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{subfiles}
%\subfile{graphs/q_value.tex}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{line}=[bend right=30,thin]
\pgfmathsetmacro\myscale{0.95}

\begin{figure}
%\centering
%The first part of figure
\begin{minipage}[]{.60\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[]{0.475\textwidth}
%%%\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(1) 1st iteration}
\end{subfigure}%
%%%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[]{0.475\textwidth}
%%%\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(2) 2nd iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}[]{0.475\textwidth}
%%%\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(3) 3rd iteration}
\end{subfigure}%
%%%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[]{0.475\textwidth}
%%%\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption*{(4) Final prediction}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
%%%%%%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[]{.38\textwidth} %Second part of figure
\begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=3mm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot[thick,dotted,edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
\deproot[red, edge height=30pt]{4}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(1) 1st iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot[thick,dotted,edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(2) 2nd iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot[edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[thick,dotted]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(3) 3rd iteration}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.3cm, font=\normalsize]
They \& were \& not \& Poles \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot[edge height=30pt]{2}{\normalsize <ROOT>}
%\deproot[edge height=30pt]{3}{\normalsize ROOT}
%\depedge[]{1}{2}{}
\depedge[]{2}{1}{}
\depedge[]{2}{3}{}
\depedge[]{2}{4}{}
\end{dependency}
\caption*{(4) Final prediction}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}


\caption{}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```